# null reference error on Zuora custom component

Tags: custom-object, visualforce-component

I am getting a null reference area trying to use Zuora's custom SelectProduct component which is using its Quote Wizard.

The only difference in the VF markup is this, original:

```
<c:SelectProduct options="{!theOptions}"/>
has been changed to this:
<zqu:SelectProduct options="{!theOptions}"/>
```

and I have switched the page in the wizard settings to point to my page (Page 3 of the Zuora Quote Wizard), instead of the managed package page from Zuora, and, I don't know why I am getting a Null Reference Error.  I am a newbie, so, I hope this isn't a completely obvious question, I am hoping what I am missing is something simple.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE - the controller code

```
public zqu.SelectProductComponentOptions theOptions { get; set; }.

theOptions = new zqu.SelectProductComponentOptions(); 
theOptions.title = 'Sample Code'; 
theOptions.subTitle = 'Choose Product and Charges'; 
theOptions.mode = zqu.SelectProductComponentOptions.MODE_EDIT;
```

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: the doc here: https://knowledgecenter.zuora.com/CA_Commerce/F_Development_Resources/C_Component_Library/B_Global_Components/SelectProduct_Component - does your VF controller have a properly constructed getter for `theOptions`

Comment: I am not sure: Here is what I have: 
public zqu.SelectProductComponentOptions theOptions { get; set; }.

Comment: then below that, I am trying to create a SelectProductComponentOptions object called theOptions:

    theOptions = new zqu.SelectProductComponentOptions();
    theOptions.title = 'Sample Code';
    theOptions.subTitle = 'Choose Product and Charges';
    theOptions.mode = zqu.SelectProductComponentOptions.MODE_EDIT;

Hope that helps.  Thanks.  -Mark

Comment: Mark -  if you set Development Mode on in your User record, the actual line number of the error will appear and that might help.

Comment: I set development mode on, but, the error doesn't say anything more than it did before:
Visualforce Error
Help for this Page

System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
Error is in expression '{!theOptions}' in component <zqu:selectproduct> in component zqu:selectproduct

I am going to pepper my class with a bunch of System.Debug statements and see if I can track down where it is complaining, but, it is Sunday, I don't think I will get to that till tomorrow, or at least later this evening.

Answer (score 0):

I got past this by adding code to check if it was null, and, setting it up in the constructor if it is.  This info was not on Zuora's website, I was lucky to find it via google.  Thanks everybody for your help.